# Dismissing 2 viewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to dismiss 2 viewControllers efficiently?

I currently have 3 viewController

View1 > presents View2 , View2 > presents View3, then when an action is triggered in View3, I need to return to the View1 Viewcontroller.

How is this done without creating a new View1 object?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or alternatively

```
int index=[[self.navigtionController viewControllers] indexOfObject:self]-2;
//make sure index is within the range of the array otherwise it will do bad things.
UIViewController *vc=[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

could be used

Comment: I dont pushViewControllers with navigationcontrollers. I present the views. [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Since they are both modally presented, your best bet would probably be to have view2 set itself as a delegate for view3, so that View3 could call the delegate method that would dismiss both view3 and view2.